# Why we see only one rainbow at some far away and not like many separated by some distance but making that same angle of 42°?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, refraction

We know that angle needed to see a rainbow assuming sun is at horizon is 42° but then why will that rainbow formation be unique and why not at that angle many rainbows be form in that angle why just a single rainbow is formed at that angle ? And will it be seen same for all height people ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't rainbows blurred-out into nothing after they are produced?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/496441/)

Comment: Thanks @John Rennie